# where should I start for creating a drag and drop quiz app using react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a  quiz app using  react where user have to fill in the blank with 4 answers option. User has to drag the correct answer to to fill the blank. where should I start to create this. Iam a beginner in this field

Comment: Before taking on high complexity projects like this, you have to invest some time in creating basic quiz system and only then, start thinking about making it 'drag and drop' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/draggable-react-components-using-react-draggable-example-application/#:%7E:text=Adding%20a%20drag%20feature%20to%20a%20component%20is,component%20to%20make%20them%20draggable%20on%20the%20page.) using react-draggable and then handle the actions as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I use [dnd-kit](https://dndkit.com/) to work with drag'n'drop in react. It has some ready to use features like sortable. But first you have to read documentation to understand correctly how it works. Don't try to use code from exmaples before you read docs.